# Unreal Engine - How to get the AxisMappings via C++ code

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm new to the Unreal Engine and C++...

I'm trying to get the assigned Key of an Axis. I found out that the information are stored in the DefaultInput.ini file but how do i access these data programmatically?

There's a GetAxisValue(const FName) method but it does not return anything.

```
FString AxisName = "MoveForward";
auto value = PlayerInputComponent->GetAxisValue(FName(*AxisName));
```

What am I doing wrong? I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this was my first thought too but unfortunately you can't get the Keys, you just bind the method to an axis name. The MoveForward's "Value" parameter hold the scale value but not the Key value. 1.0f for example when you press "W" or -1.0f when you press "S".

I've already found a solution for my issue. The GetAxisValue(FName) is the wrong method for this purpose.

Instead I found the UInputSettings class that contains a method named GetAxisMappingByName(FName, TArray)

Here a code snippet how it works:

```
// Get the instance of the InputSettings
UInputSettings* InputSettings = UInputSettings::GetInputSettings();

// AxisMappings with all the information will be stored here
TArray<FInputAxisKeyMapping> VerticalKeys;
TArray<FInputAxisKeyMapping> HorizontalKeys;

// Load the AxisMappings
InputSettings->GetAxisMappingByName(FName("MoveForward"), VerticalKeys);
InputSettings->GetAxisMappingByName(FName("MoveRight"), HorizontalKeys);

// Each MovementKey gets its own variable
FKey ForwardKey;
FKey BackKey;
FKey LeftKey;
FKey RightKey;

// Assign each key to the correct direction
for (FInputAxisKeyMapping verticalKey : VerticalKeys)
{
    if (verticalKey.Scale == 1.0f)
        ForwardKey = verticalKey.Key;
    else if (verticalKey.Scale == -1.0f)
        BackKey = verticalKey.Key;
}

for (FInputAxisKeyMapping horizontalKey : HorizontalKeys)
{
    if (horizontalKey.Scale == 1.0f)
        RightKey = horizontalKey.Key;
    else if (horizontalKey.Scale == -1.0f)
        LeftKey = horizontalKey.Key;
}
```

Is there a better solution for assigning the keys than using for loops? Feel free to correct my code since I'm not really an expert in C++. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure because I use Blueprints most of the time for this, but one way to get the value is to bind it to a method.

(Example of the AFPSCharacter Template)

```
PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("MoveForward", this, &APawn::MoveForward);
```

And later use it in the method

```
void AFPSCharacter::MoveForward(float Value){
//for example print the val
 UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%f"), Value);
}
```